# Loading an image with jQuery after clicking a Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, href, loading

I would like to load an image from a Link:

**1)** Click on "a href", extract image url from href/src/id

**2)** Link should dissapear and show Ajax-Loader Image while loading Image.

**3)** Display loaded image.

If it's possible i dont want to use any buttons or div-constructs to output image - only a simple link.

On Click:

```
<a class="loc" href="./misc/images/image1.png"></a>
```

Browser should output an image:

```
<img src="./misc/images/image1.png" />
```

so far i made this:

```
$('a.loc').text('load image').css("cursor","pointer");
$('.loc').click(function(){

  $(".loc").fadeOut(300);
  $(".loc").html('<img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
  var image = $(this).attr('src');

  *** how to show/load image, how to use my var ??? ***

});
```

Has anybody an idea how to complete this task? I'm, greatful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/):

```
var image = $(this).attr('src');
$(this).replaceWith('<img src="'+ image +'">');
```

However your method to show a loading image will not work more. You should add some [prefetching logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery) to your codes and use `replaceWith` after fetching image.